# RequestParam with specific index

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

In a spring boot application, I search to support this kind of request with a rest controller

```
partyrole?account[0].id=18
```

Comment: This king? or This kind?. Bring seasoned user at SO shouldnt you elaborate your question a little more? Like what you tried so far, what do you expect and what error you are trying to resolve here?

Comment: Do you need the value in square brackets as well?

Comment: Have you tried the ```@RequestParam List<IdsDto> account```? Where IdsDto is a class that contains the Id.